# Trigger video overlay gif with a button press?

Tags: javascript, html

So from what I understand the `poster` attribute for the video tag allows you to overlay images and gifs on a video. I'm wondering if there's a way to only activate that gif that the  `poster` attribute is assigned to when I press a button?

The app I'm making takes images from the user's web cam and I just want to give some feedback to them in the form of that loading gif after they press the button.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
<script>
  function addPoster() {
    document.getElementById('video')
      .setAttribute('poster', 'http://placekitten.com/300/200')
  }
</script>
<button onclick="addPoster()">Add Poster</button>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/su81ro2b/2/

Comment: This doesn't work when there is a video feed being sent to the video element. What I mean by this is that when I request the camera from the user, and then set the poster attribute, the poster doesn't appear. However it does appear if you set it BEFORE the user turns on their camera.